# Gnome Start search window

Tags: gnome, xmonad

When I start my computer using Gnome (well, Gnome + Xmonad), this search window appears that prompts me to search my computer. I'd really like to disable that. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: After doing some research I've found this is the famous Gnome Do (Having some trouble taking a screenshot of it at startup). How do I prevent this from opening at startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running GNOME Do, then there are two options.

### Start-up Applications

You can open start-up applications by running `gnome-session-properties`.

[image: Start-up Applications]

From here you can disable Gnome-Do.

---

### GNOME Do's Preferences

The other option is to disable running Gnome-Do on start-up from within GNOME Do's preferences.

[image: Gnome-Do Preferences]

Make sure that the check box that says "Start GNOME Do at login." is unchecked.